# What's the meaning of "to go around" here?

Tags: word-meaning

> There’s only so much empathy to go around, but it’s possible to
>   achieve economies of sorts.

There are some meanings for to [go around](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/go-around):

- visit a person/place
- how someone behaves/dresses
- be given/told to people
- spend time with someone
- be enough for everyone
- move in a circle

I don't understand which one is better.

So, Could you explain it to me? Could you please tell me what the sentence means?

The fuller text is here:

> Make it less of a sacrifice
>
> Our mindsets can either intensify or
>   lessen our susceptibility to empathy overload. For example, we
>   exacerbate the zero-sum problem when we assume that our own interests
>   and others’ are fundamentally opposed. (This often happens in deal
>   making, when parties with different positions on an issue get stuck
>   because they’re obsessed with the gap between them.) An adversarial
>   mindset not only prevents us from understanding and responding to the
>   other party but also makes us feel as though we’ve “lost” when we
>   don’t get our way. We can avoid burnout by seeking integrative
>   solutions that serve both sides’ interests. Take this example: A
>   salary negotiation between a hiring manager and a promising candidate
>   will be come a tug-of-war contest if they have different numbers in
>   mind and fi xate on the money alone. But let’s suppose that the
>   candidate actually cares more about job security, and the manager is
>   keenly interested in avoiding turnover. Building security into the
>   contract would be a win-win: an empathic act by the manager that
>   wouldn’t drain his empathy reserves the way making a concession on
>   salary would, because keeping new hires around is in line with his own
>   desires.
>   **There’s only so much empathy to go around, but it’s possible to achieve economies of sorts**. By asking questions instead of letting
>   assumptions go unchecked, you can bring such solutions to the surface.

Answer (score 1):

You've actually got it spot on in one of your definitions:

> be enough for everyone

I.e.

> There is only so much empathy **for everyone to share**.